# Redux - React Hook Form connectivity

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form v7 with redux-toolkit in my react project. I have multiple forms under FormContext. Is there any way to sync form's data with redux store synchronously?
Actually, there is information about this in the official document, but I did not fully understand how redux connect works and what is meant by updateAction.

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import updateAction from "./actions";

export default function App(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    }
  });
  // Submit your data into Redux store
  const onSubmit = data => props.updateAction(data);
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName")} />
      <input {...register("lastName")} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

// Connect your component with redux
connect(({ firstName, lastName }) => ({ firstName, lastName }), updateAction)(YourForm);
```

The redux store should appear like this:

```
{
// other state values
lorem : {...},
ipsum : {...},
// form state values
form1: {
input1: ...,
...,
}
// OR
formContext: {
 form1: {..}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways of doing this but I used [`watch`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/).

```
const { watch } = useForm({ mode: "all" }}
```

It's important to use a mode other than the default `onSubmit` on `useForm` if you want synchronous updates. I used `mode: "all"` which triggers updates on both `blur` and `change` events.

---

Create a redux slice using [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice)

```
export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: "form",
  initialState: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    updateForm(state, action) {
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    },
  },
});

export const { updateForm } = formSlice.actions;

export default formSlice.reducer;
```

---

Subscribe to `watch` and dispatch action `updateForm`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value) => {
      dispatch(updateForm(value));
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [dispatch, watch]);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-w-reduxjs-toolkit-update-on-change-blur-uehxxs?file=/src/MyForm.js)